# Raw SQL 'Insert Into' in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to insert data from a form into two tables in db.

```
public ActionResult Cr([Bind(Include = "id,name,time")] appointment appointment, [Bind(Include = "pid,phone")] customer customer , string submit)
        {
        string str1 = "Insert Into appointment.id, appointment.name, appointment.time Values id,name,time"
        string str2= "Insert Into customer.pid, customer.phone Values pid,phone"
        var Query = dbb.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModel.custapp>(str1).ToList();
        var Query = dbb.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModel.custapp>(str2).ToList();
        return View("Index");
        }
```

I am not sure if my code is wrong but the data are not inserted in the tables.

Comment: I suggest you use parameterized query for both inserts and a viewmodel instead. The query seems valid but doesn't insert data since required values probably not bound to action method.

Comment: The Syntax must be `insert into ... values ( ...)`:

Answer (score 1):

You need table name  (column name)  and values  (  )

```
string str1 = "Insert Into  appointment (id, name, time)  Values (id,name,time)";
string str2= "Insert Into  customer (pid, phone)  Values (pid,phone)";
```

Comment: i changed my code exactly like yours but it seems like the columns cannot be found. The error is `Invalid column name 'id'`

Comment: @hud id should be of same name as column name of id in table

Comment: @hud ...which is thename of   the columns in db table  and the name of the var where you sore the correspondant value?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you wrote the query string wrong, the correct syntax for insertion of data into table is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column 1, column 2, ...) VALUES (values)
```

The query string should be:

```
string str1 = "Insert Into appointment (id, name, time) Values (id, name, time)";
string str2 = "Insert Into customer (pid, phone) Values (pid, phone)";
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: i changed my code exactly like yours but it seems like the columns cannot be found. The error is Invalid column name 'id'

Answer (score 1):

since you are inserting the data your code should be like this

```
var sql = @"Insert Into appointment (name, time) Values (@name, @time)";
int noOfRowInserted = dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
    new SqlParameter("@name", appointment.name),
    new SqlParameter("@time", appointment.time));
```

i used parameters to prevent `sql injection` and `SqlQuery<entity>` this command is used when you are returning some data which will be of type `entity` but in your case you are inserting data. for further information check this 
[RAW SQL QUERY](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)